# Cannot give necessary input to C++ program in windows console

Tags: c++, command-prompt, geany

I'm trying to solve [CSES Problem Set: Apartments](https://cses.fi/problemset/task/1084/), which have input like this in 3 lines, but I am unable to process/pass all three lines in the Windows terminal. I am using Geany editor and compilation is successful.

```
10 10 0
37 62 56 69 34 46 10 86 16 49
50 95 47 43 9 62 83 71 71 7
```

Can anyone review and tell me what is wrong? Is there fault in my logic?

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int n, m, k;

int main()
{
    vector<int> v1;
    vector<int> v2;
    vector<bool> allotted(n, false);

    cin >> n >> m >> k;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        cin >> v1[i];
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
        cin >> v2[j];
    }

    sort(v2.begin(), v2.end());
    sort(v1.begin(), v1.end());
    int ans = 0;
    for (int req = 0; req < n; ++req) {
        for (int x = -k; x <= k; ++x) {
            if (find(v2.begin(), v2.end(), v1[req]+x) != v2.end() && alloted[req] == false) {
                ++ans;
                allotted[req] = 1;
            }
            else {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << ans;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
10 10 0
37 62 56 69 34 46 10 86 16 49


------------------
(program exited with code: -1073741819)
```

Comment: Strap it into a debugger and find out what's going on.

Comment: `-1073741819` is the same as `0xC0000005` and it means Access Violation on windows.

Answer (score 3):

You must allocate elements before accessing them or add elements via `push_back`.

To allocate elements, using `resize()` is one good way.

```
vector<int> v1;
vector<int> v2;
vector<bool> allotted(n, false); // note that n is zero here!

cin>>n>>m>>k; // after here, the size will be n (may not when the reading fails)

// allocate elements
v1.resize(n);
v2.resize(m);
allotted.resize(n);
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to tell your vectors how long they should be. As a result you 're reading data into non-existing variables.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to MikeCAT's answer, if you delay the declaration of your vectors until you know how big they need to be then you can create them at the correct size.

```
cin>>n>>m>>k;
vector<int> v1(n); // v1 has size n
vector<int> v2(m); // v2 has size m
vector<bool> allotted(n, false); // allotted has size n
```